# Stop Chrome from AutoFill email/password on React test sites?

Tags: reactjs

Hi my specific issue is that I can't get rid of an email/password that autofills no matter what I do. I am using a mac and Chrome is my browser.

[This is what happens every time I try to log in to an app I am making](https://i.stack.imgur.com/li0er.png)

I have tried deleting all saved passwords, selecting the email/password then entering fn-delete, deleting my cookies/emptying cache. Nothing works.

Please help, it's really frustrating trying to test my app or demonstrate any app and having this autofill.

Answer (score 2):

You can try to enable/disable your field onFocus and onBlur, something like this:

```
    ...
    const [readOnly, setReadOnly] = useState(true);
      return (
          <input
            readOnly={readOnly}
            onFocus={ () => setReadOnly(false) }
            onBlur={ () => setReadOnly(true) }
          />
      );
     ...
```

Comment: based on all the discussion [here](https://gist.github.com/niksumeiko/360164708c3b326bd1c8), and the different tricks that I tried, seems like your answer is the only solution, thanks a million!

Answer (score 0):

You should add the `autoComplete="disabled"` prop to each input field you dont want to have auto-fill.

[Here's a good read on the topic](https://gist.github.com/niksumeiko/360164708c3b326bd1c8). You should go to the bottom of the thread to see working answers as browsers change their compatibility over the years.

Comment: It still shows up when I have this added to my code.

Answer (score 0):

`autocomplete="new-password"` will do the trick for Chrome.